# I am needed for books

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Children lie and say they have my prefix when they don't want to go to school.

Dating singles will use my infix to refer to the 2 of them.

Wise men will examine my suffix so that they could improve upon themselves.

Every children's book needs someone doing my whole word.

What am I?

Answer (score 4):

Children lie and say they have my prefix when they don't want to go to school.

> They might say they are ILL

Dating singles will use my infix to refer to the 2 of them.

> The two of them are US

Wise men will examine my suffix so that they could improve upon themselves.

> They can examine their RATING to improve

Every children's book needs someone doing my whole word.
What am I?

> The children’s books need someone ILLUSTRATING

Comment: very nice. I was thinking illustrate. (the wise men examin their traits). but  urs actually kinda better lol

Comment: Is saying CHildren (two capitals) intentional? Did I miss something?